# Converting dataframe into rdd with losing header columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried the below but header columns are coming after the data, ideally it should be the first column!

can anyone help me on this please!

```
val header = sc.parallelize(Seq(df.columns.mkString("|"))) 
val data = df.map(_.mkString("|")) 
val final = header.union(data) 
final.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("path")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

why don't you write dataframe to file directly.

use below code for writing pipe seperated dataframe to file:

```
mydf.coalesce(1)
      .write
      .option("header","true")
      .option("sep","|")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .csv("output/path")
```

for converting dataframe into rdd, simply use `mydf.rdd`

Comment: Hi millions of records if i use coalesce(1) it will run very slowly